# Sort a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

want to sort a linked list, but my code doesnt want to:)

Here it is:

```
void swap(element *p,element*q) {
    int aux;

    aux=p->info;
    p->info=q->info;
    q->info=aux;
}

void ordonare(element *lista) {
    element *p,*q;

    for(p=lista; p!=NULL; p=p->urmator) {
        if(p->info>p->urmator->info) {
            swap(p,p->urmator);
        }
    }
}
```

If this works, it will only sort the values, without changing the nodes' positions.
I can't seem to find the bug here, and I would appreciate if you could also indicate the solution where the nodes will change their positions.

Thanks, 
Radu

UPDATE

the code above works, but as @Daniel.S mentioned, it only does one iteration through the list.

What conditions am I supposed to put in order to iterate until it is sorted?

Thanks!!:)

Comment: In the comment below my answer, you said that your program doesn't run at all. So what does it do? Does it give any error message? Does it run without termination? Does it run, but you see no effect?

Comment: It just stops working when it comes to this part in code.

Comment: What happened when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: It is a segmentation fault.

Comment: The segmentation fault indicates that some pointer is not initialized correctly. Please show us the code which populates the list. The problem is most likely there.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), it is perfect for lists and easy to implement. That link has an example implementation:

> Merge sort is often the best choice for sorting a linked list: in this situation it is relatively easy to implement a merge sort in such a way that it requires only Θ(1) extra space, and the slow random-access performance of a linked list makes some other algorithms (such as quicksort) perform poorly, and others (such as heapsort) completely impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting algorithm is not complete. You're missing parts in the loop. One loop iteration over the list is not enough. Example:

You have the list {3,2,1}. If you sort it with your algorithm, it will first compare 3 and 2 and swap them, then you get

{2,3,1} it will then compare 3 and 1 and swap those, too. Then you get {2,1,3}. Your algorithm finishes here, but the list isn't sorted yet.

Depending on the algorithm you want to implement (e.g. bubble sort), you have to add additional code.

What algorithm do you want to implement?

Comment: Ok, I see that it would not sort the entire list, but with near elements, it should swap them, but it doesn't run at all. Yes, some sort of bubble.
Thanks for the reply!:)

Comment: When it comes to this part in the code, the program stops working.

Comment: Please specify what "stops working" is. I'm sorry, but you'll have to explain this. Otherwise I don't know what problem you are having and I wouldn't be able to help any further.

Comment: program_name.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working properly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.